# React recharts : Pie chart is not rendering

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am not able to render Pie charts, I cannot see that I am doing anything incorrectly (based on what I see in examples and documentation)

Data and Colors:

```
const piedata = [
    { name: "Technology", value: props.data.tech },
    { name: "Services", value: props.data.services },
    {
      name: "Communication",
      value: props.data.communication,
    },
    { name: "Others", value: props.data.others },
  ];

  const PieColors = ["#bce893", "#44a7e1", "#556cfb", "#f4b040"];
```

props are in this form

```
data: EquityAllocation(
communication: 6.1,
others: 2.7,
services: 7.5,
tech: 83.6
)
```

[console.log(props)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGddf.png)

Code for Piechart:

```
<PieChart width="400px" height="400px">
          <Pie
            data={piedata}
            cx="50%"
            cy="50%"
            innerRadius={60}
            outerRadius={200}
            paddingAngle={5}
            fill="#82ca9d"
            dataKey="value"
            nameKey="name"
          >
            {piedata.map((entry, index) => (
              <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={PieColors[index]} />
            ))}
          </Pie>
        </PieChart>
```

I am using **"recharts": "^2.1.8",**

Example in official docs : https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithPaddingAngle

Nothing is printed in logs also, no errors or warnings. I also started whole app again but still, charts are not rendering.

Comment: The data in the prop is not valid JSON. can you correct it? Console log props.data and attach to your question

Comment: I have attached the snapshot of console.log(props)

Answer (score 0):

So I started the migration to MUIv5 and also upgraded to the latest version of recharts and ran into the same issue. Some of my charts stopped rendering.
The observation that I'm having right now is that the chart wants `width` or `height` as an actual numeric value. Try switching `width="400px" height="400px"` to `width={400} height={400}`.

That's what they also have in their Demo charts.